# pip fails to install PIL or Pillow with mt.exe error

Tags: python, windows-7, python-imaging-library, pip

On one of my Windows 7 development machines, I am attempting to install the Python Image Library.

My machines are similar. Both run Windows 7 Professional, x64. Both use Python 2.7.3 (32bit). On one of the machine `pip install PIL` works fine. On the other it fails with the trace ending with this:

```
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.pyd.manifest : general error c1010070:
 Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.

error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks to http://bugs.python.org/issue4431, this error was fixed by modifying:

```
C:\<Python dir>\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py
```

and adding:

```
 ld_args.append('/MANIFEST')
```

after the MANIFESTFILE line so it looks like:

```
        # Embedded manifests are recommended - see MSDN article titled
        # "How to: Embed a Manifest Inside a C/C++ Application"
        # (currently at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591(VS.80).aspx)
        # Ask the linker to generate the manifest in the temp dir, so
        # we can embed it later.
        temp_manifest = os.path.join(
                build_temp,
                os.path.basename(output_filename) + ".manifest")
        ld_args.append('/MANIFESTFILE:' + temp_manifest)
        ld_args.append('/MANIFEST')
```

If you still get the error, then change the `if arg.startswith("/MANIFESTFILE:")` to `if arg.startswith("/MANIFEST:")` in the `manifest_get_embed_info(self, target_desc, ld_args)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Download the compressed package from pypi, and try building and installing in your machine. This **[link](http://fuyun.org/2009/12/install-mysql-for-python-on-windows/)** could give you some hints. That exactly deals with your problem only but the installation varies.

Answer (score 1):

If you've reached here looking for

```
general error c1010070:
 Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.

error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31
```

Here's a workaround that worked in Windows 8/x64/Python 3.3/VS 11:

```
# py 3.3 seems to be compiled against VS 2010 compiler, force using VS11 cl.exe for us
$env:VS100COMNTOOLS=$env:VS110COMNTOOLS

# Modify C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py
# Comment line 670:         ld_args.append('/MANIFESTFILE:' + temp_manifest)
# Basically it will instruct build to not look for manifest file
```